# Should we use Amazon CloudFront? (We need mitigate cost attacks)

Tags: hacking, amazon-s3, business, ddos

We want to serve our files from Amazon S3.

We are worried about cost DoS attacks (deliberately downloading files from Amazon many times, in order for us to pay a big bill to Amazon).

We don't have enough money to use AWS Shield Advanced now.

Question: Will serving S3 not directly but through CloudFront help to reduce possible cost attacks? How much (if any) does it help against cost attacks?

Answer (score 1):

A user or bots downloading the same file again and again is not a DOS attack. Cloudflare provides unmetered DOS attacks:

> Cloudflare’s unmetered mitigation of DDoS stops illegitimate
>   volumetric traffic at the Cloudflare edge. All Cloudflare plans
>   include unmetered mitigation without fear of being dropped.

Cloudflare will cache these [file formats](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) and [up to 512MB](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200394750-What-s-the-maximum-file-size-Cloudflare-will-cache-) a file for Free, Pro and Business accounts.

Cloudflare will reduce your server-side traffic from around 50-75% and will vary depending on your traffic, page rules and how your site is built and what it hosts.

If your expecting an approximate saving then you will be waiting a long time since no one will be able to answer that.

Comment: Cloudflare also puts a check on suspicious behaviour. Plus, even if a user (or bot) downloads the same file over and over it *should* be cached but that depends on your web server setup specifics - it is fairly straightforward to almost force caching or deny caching of particular resources in most cases.